# Having an issue with exceptions regarding input from a .txt file

Tags: java

Hi I'm currently creating a program which will allow me to input the path of a .txt file with a format of:

Home Name : Away Name : Home Score : Away Score

Liverpool : Chelsea : 2 : 1

Spurs : Fulham : 1 : 1

and it should output into the console in order. However, I am having trouble with my exceptions. I am trying to get it to display so that if either parameter is missing such as the delimiter, team name/score is missing it will output an error to the console. I want it so that it will display all missing parameters and not just one. For example, Home team name is missing. Away team name is missing. No field delimiter. Invalid home score, check it is a whole number.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

The current code which I have now is:

Comment: You should almost always log exceptions you encounter, certainly if you already know that something does not work as expected.

Comment: Unless you know an Exception can be ignored, I would print it out and look at the line in which the error occurred. Then I would step through the program in your debugger to see why the application behaves the way it does.

Comment: If I have an empty field such as "Away Team Name" it doesn't throw an error. It will continue printing to the console without that team name.

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println()` you should make `throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ("some text")` if you want to catch your exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is cause the first line of your file is a header 
Home Name : Away Name : Home Score : Away Score

And when you will try to parse the splitted text into `int`, it will failed to parse and will throw an error at the following line in your code

```
int homeScore = Integer.parseInt(splitText[2].trim());
```

I hope this gives you a direction to find a solution to your question. Although it's quite difficult to 'guess' the issue as there isn't any error stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned that there is no header in the file. What I put above is just to show you how I have formatted it in the file.

Comment: Do your have extra line breaks in the file, as you've added above in the sample?

Comment: No extra breaklines. It is in the format as listed above with multiple different entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all errors you shouldn't use exceptions. Those are meant to be used in case something unexpected happens. Instead you should do checks like that `splitText[0].length() == 0` etc. and collect all the errors. That being said, the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` could be replaced by a check for `splitText.length < 4` (and of course the following checks need to take that into consideration as well).

That `NumberFormatException` could be an exception for that rule because you'd either have to check whether the string is a number and then try to parse it or just try it and catch the exception to know it isn't a number.

Your code could then look like this:

```
List<String> errors = new LinkedList<>();
if( splitText.length < 4) {
   errors.add("Fields might be missing")
} 

//do other checks here

//if all fields are present, check the numbers (this could be done in some method)
int homeScore = -1;
try {
  homeScore = Integer.parseInt(splitText[2].trim());
} catch( NumberFormatException e) {
  errors.add("Homescore is not an integer");
}

//other checks and then finally:

if( errors.isEmpty() ) { 
  //everything ok
} else {
  //print the collected errors
}
```

Note that some checks don't make sense if others already failed, i.e. parsing away score doesn't make sense if the length of the array is smaller than 4 or if the 4th element is an empty string (at least after trimming). That would have to be taken into account.

Comment: Hi. How would I go about printing the collected errors? Thanks.

Comment: @Phenj well, you already printed errors, didn't you (your question doesn't contain code anymore). Since that list contains the errors for each line (i.e. it should be recreated or cleared when checking the next input line) you'd just have to iterate over the strings in that list and print them.